# TypeError: "embedded NUL character" to stick little pictures on a white picture

Tags: image, character, python-imaging-library, nul

I want to create a "DOBBLE" game, but,
to create a DOBBLE card game, I just want to put some symbols (little pictures) on a bigger, but the Shell return this:

> "embedded NUL character".

My program is:

```
def creer_carte(L):

S=associer() #a list of little pictures' link : ['1.jpg','2.jpg',..]
size=(700,450) #dimension de l'image finale
newim=Image.new('RGB',size,"white") #on créé une image vide
newim.save("carteblanche.jpg", "PNG")
for i in range(len(L)):

    A=open(S[L[i+1]],encoding='latin-1').read()
    img=Image.open(A) #On télécharge le fichier
    newim.paste(img,(i*200,0))
newim.show()
return None
```

...It's only the beginning of my program.

Comment: It's very unlikely that you want to open an image file as if it consisted of latin-1 encoded text.  Image files typically contain binary data that is not only meaningless gibberish, but has values which are not a valid coding of *any* text - probably a 0x00 in this case.  **Also don't play tag roulette.**